# Backup using the Script Tool of h2 via shellscript in Git bash

Tags: git, shell, backup, h2

I try to save my h2-db-tables into a zip-file by using the command:

```
java -cp C:/User/Adrian/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.189/h2-1.4.189.jar
org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:~/test -user sa -script test.zip -options compression zip
```

but i always get the error : java : cammand not found.
I'm working with git bash on windows and included the java path to its bin-folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a regular CMD windows, and type `java -version`.

If this work, then from that same CMD window, cd to where git is installed, and type `git-bash`: that will open a bash session that should inherit the `PATH` from the CMD window. Confirm by typing java -version.

Finally, cd to where your project is, and type your java command.

Comment: @MrKnorke Great! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote